# arrow function Parsing error: Unexpected token >

Tags: javascript, function, eslint, arrow-functions

I get a syntax error on line 7. I can not understand why. Here is the code below, and below that is a picture of the error. I realize that this question may be a duplicate, but I can not find a solution to my problem.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];

arr.indexOf() == -1;

var arr = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];

var usersIds = arr.map(user => user.id);

arr.map(user => user.id).forEach( id => { console.log(id) } );

arr.map(user=> user.status = "ACTIVE");
```

.eslintrc:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "more"
  ],

  "rules": {
    'more/no-void-map': 2,
    "more/no-c-like-loops": 2,
    "more/prefer-includes": 2,
    "more/no-then": 2,
    "more/no-window": 2,
    "more/no-numeric-endings-for-variables": 2,
    "more/force-native-methods": 2,
    "more/no-duplicated-chains": 2,
    "more/classbody-starts-with-newline": [2, 'never']
  }
}
```

Error:

[image]

I received the error from my newly installed package `eslint`, if that helps.

Below are my eslint and node version:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you can even use arrow functions? (ES6 compatible)?

Comment: what does your .eslintrc file look like? ESLint defaults to ES 5...

Comment: What version of ESLint?

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but I found atom linters (particularly typescript) to be a little buggy, throwing errors based on code that had been changed. Is the error still there if you close and reopen Atom?

Comment: Sounds like the environment you're using doesn't understand arrow functions. That code is syntactically valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your esLint version is outdated. Can you check again if the version of esLint is compatible with es6 Arrow functions.

Perhabs you can try [`babel-eslint`](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set:

```
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6
}
```

in your eslint configuration file to enable the ES6 parser. The default parser is the ES5 one. Arrow functions are not valid ES5.